# Create CSV with diverse & big data

Tags: javascript, csv, lodash

I know the process of creating a CSV file so my question is more specific to the data that I have. I have some recorders and each of them has some data. Each data consists of the value and a timestamp. So a recorder looks like this:

```
'recorder_name': {
    samples: [{v: 19, t: new Date()}]
}
```

The problem is that not all recorders have values for all timestamps and they do not have the same amount of data. I started playing around with `lodash` but it is really slow. What I have so far is the following:

```
function createCSVRows(data) {
    const timestamps = [];
    const csvRows = [];

    //data contains all recorders
    _.forEach(data, ({samples}) => {
        _.forEach(samples, s => {
            const timestamp = moment(s.t).utc();
            timestamps.push(timestamp.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
        });
    });

    _(timestamps)
        .uniq()
        .sortBy(t => moment(t).utc())
        .forEach(t => {
            const csvRow = [t];

            _.forEach(data, ({samples}) => {
                const value = _.find(samples, s => moment(s.t).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') === t);

                if(!value) {
                    csvRow.push('');
                } else {
                    csvRow.push(value.v);
                }
            });
            csvRows.push(csvRow);
        })
        .value();

    return csvRows;
}
```

So, I try to get all available timestamps and then keep only the unique ones. The problem is how to get out the value for each timestamp. The `find` function is what takes much time, since each recorder has an average of 500-600 data points. I have never seen the function execute till the end since the browser tab dies after a short time.

Thanks

**EDIT**: As per @charlietfl 's comment I've also tried the following:

```
_.forEach(data, ({samples}) => {
    _.forEach(samples, s => {
        const timestamp = moment(s.t).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        if(!timestamps[timestamp]) {
            timestamps[timestamp] = [];
        }

        _.forEach(timestamps, (v, t) => {
            if(t === timestamp) {
                v.push(s.v);
            } else {
                v.push('');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The problem again is that I have to loop over the timestamps because I have to fill all other timestamps with empty values. The tab still dies. Any ideas?

**EDIT 2**:
Sample data:

```
{
   'recorder_a': {
       samples: [{t: new Date(2015,02,03), v: 10}, {t: new Date(2015,02,04), v: 15}]
    },
   'recorder_b': {
       samples: [{t: new Date(2015,02,03), v: 11}] 
    }
}
```

and the expected CSV should look something like this:

```
Date         recorder_a    recorder_b
2015-02-03       10            11
2015-02-04       15             -
```

By that I mean that if a recorder doesn't have a value for a timestamp then I have to show an empty shell.

Comment: More efficient to create an object where timestamps are keys. Iterate once and check if key exists or not. Then iterate object to map back to array. Will remove the repetitive array searching that `find()` is doing

Comment: @charlietfl you mean instead of adding the timestamps in an array?

Comment: could you maybe provide a small example?

Comment: Yes..  right from the start. Add timestamp to object if it doesn't exist and assign value as row. Ignore if it already exists

Comment: oh I see, will test it and let you know

Comment: @charlietfl can you check my edit? I tried you solution but still the same.

Comment: Provide  simple sample of data for input and expected results. Your second version is still looping all timestamps within another loop so the whole timestamp object hasn't even been created then

Comment: @charlietfl I edited again, please have a look

Comment: So do you know how many columns? Or is that part of the whole issue?

Comment: so the column count needs to be calculated first?

Comment: it's the length of the keys of the `data` object but we don't need to know the length somewhere.

Comment: oh yes...I see it...so it would be `Object.keys(data).length`

Comment: yes exactly! do you have something in mind?

Comment: try this  https://jsfiddle.net/0ebcsghp/. Not a csv expert so can set it up any way you need within helper functions

Comment: thanks, it is working with some small adjustments to my code. would you like to write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that should work. Uses objects instead of arrays to cut down on a lot of array searching within loops

```
// object to store dates as keys
var dates = {} // {'2015-12-22':{recorder_a:4, recorder_c:7}}
// array of recorder names
var recorders = Object.keys(data);
// populate dates object with known recorders per date
recorders.forEach(function(recorder) {
  data[recorder].samples.forEach(function(sample) {
    var dateStr = getDateString(sample.t)
    if (!dates[dateStr]) {
      dates[dateStr] = {}
    }
    dates[dateStr][recorder] = sample.v
  });
});
// array of date keys sorted
var datesArr = Object.keys(dates).sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a) - new Date(b);
});

var headings= ['Date'].concat(recorders);
// now fill in missing recorders on each date
var res = [csvRow(headings)];
datesArr.forEach(function(date) {
  var row = [date],
    rowData = dates[date];
  recorders.forEach(function(recorder) {
    var value = rowData.hasOwnProperty(recorder) ? rowData[recorder] : '';
    row.push(value)
  });
  res.push(csvRow(row))
});

// final csv result string 
var csv = res.join('')


// row csv helper
function csvRow(arr){
  return '"'+ arr.join('","')+'"\n'
}
// helper
function getDateString(date) {
  return date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0ebcsghp/)**</kbd>

Comment: for some reason the date sorting is not working correctly everywhere. had to return `new Date(a)-new Date(b)`

Comment: yeah...I threw that in as a quicky just for concept. String compare not the best